# jquery select not class form multiclass assignment

Tags: jquery, selector

Hi i am having the follow code

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element NOTME"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

the code below select the inputs inside container with class element

```
$("#container .element input[name^='myname']").each
```

How can i rewrite the above code (the selector actually) that will exclude when has class NOTME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the qualifier `:not(.NOTME)`:

```
$('#container .element:not(.NOTME) input[name^=myname]').each( ... )
```

The `:not()` can reference any selector expression, of course.

Comment: Sorry i was using .element:not(".NOTME"). Thanks